# Python 3 POST request 400 error

Tags: python-3.x, http, curl, post

I'm trying to send request with urllib:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

api_key = ""
base_url_string = 'URL'
values = {'api_key' : api_key}

user_agent = 'curl/7.47.0'
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
           'User-Agent': user_agent,
           'Accept' : '*/*'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
request = urllib.request.Request(url=base_url_string, data=data, headers=headers)

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    json_response = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))

    for line in json_response:
        print(line)

except URLError as e:
    print(e)
```

and get "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"api_key":""}' URL
```

works fine.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are announcing `application/json` as the content type. But what you are actually encoding through [`urllib.parse.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try with [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) instead.

Comment: data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values) became data = json.dumps(values) and it worked